# Subclass UIStackView to ack as observer

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to subclass UIStackView to act as observable to i can bind an observer to it. Basically i want to pass an observer and for every element i want to add a subview into the stack.
So basically i would have `var myObs: Observable<CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType>` and i want to do `myObs.bind(to: myCustomStackView)` and add a subview for every element.

This is what i tried so far:

```
protocol CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType {
    var title: String { get }
}

class CustomStackViewUIStackView<E>: UIStackView, ObserverType where E:CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType  {
    typealias E = CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType

    func on(_ event: Event<CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType>) {
        switch event {
        case .next(let value): nextElement(value)
        case .completed: break
        case .error(_): break
        }
    }

    func nextElement(e: CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType) {
        let someViewForStack = SomeViewForStack.init(e: e)
        self.insertSubview(someViewForStack, at: 0)
    }

    class SomeViewForStack: UIView {
        init(e: CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType) {}
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}
    }
}
```

But resulting in the error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Event'
[image]

Comment: The problem is related to the Event class so can you show details of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just refactored your code a bit for better understanding. And the problem disappeared. The code compiles.

Btw, specify the version of **Swift** and **RxSwift** you use.

Anyway, providing the refactored code, it might help:

```
protocol CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType {

    var title: String { get }
}

class CustomStackViewUIStackView<Element>: UIStackView, ObserverType where Element: CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType  {

    func on(_ event: Event<Element>) {
        switch event {
        case .next(let element):
            nextElement(element: element)
        case .completed:
            break
        case .error:
            break
        }
    }

    func nextElement(element: CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType) {
        let view = SomeViewForStack(element: element)
        self.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
    }

    class SomeViewForStack: UIView {

        init(element: CanBeDisplayInMyStackViewType) {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had namespace problem ( i got another Event class )

Comment: How do you link items from an array to this CustomStackview?

Comment: @PabloMartinez create some BehaviorRelay and make a bindning bind(to: your CustomStackviewIntance). Whenever BehaviorRelay value is changed your stack view will be redrawn